# Callback para un sonido en Processing

Tags: java, sonido, processing

En p5js (el "hermano gemelo" de Processing para Javascript) existe una función llamada `preload()`, que sirve para cargar los archivos antes que cualquier otra función.

En Processing también se pueden cargar archivos (en mi caso un archivo de sonido) de esta manera:

```
import processing.sound.*;

SoundFile sonido;

void setup() {
  sonido = new SoundFile(this, "archivo.mp3");
}
```

El problema es que si justo despues de declarar la variable "sonido" pongo `sonido.play();` van a saltar errores (concretamente NullPointerException)

Yo supongo que es porque no le da tiempo a cargar el sonido, porque si pruebo con archivos mp3 de 1 segundo en vez de 5 o 10, si funciona.

Y ahí esta el problema, que quiero saber si existe alguna manera de solucionar esto. He pensado que podría hacer que nada funcione hasta que un callback de `new SoundFile()` lo diga, pero no se si ese callback existe, o como hacer que se active.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: En la documentación no pone nada de que haya que esperar. Podrías [edit] la pregunta y añadir el stacktrace de ese NPE para ayudarnos a averiguar qué está pasando.

Comment: no se que es un stacktrace pero simplemente sale en rojo en la "consola" de processing: "NullPointerException" y se marca automaticamente la linea de "sonido.play()"

Answer (score 0):

Debes de poner tu archivo en la carpeta `data` dentro de la carpeta de tu proyecto.

Si tienes duda, he hallado un [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJJCci3kXe0) de como hacerlo.

Si necesitas la documentación de SoundFile está en su [página oficial](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/SoundFile.html).

Si te preocupa crear una NPE, puedesvalidar a la antiguita

```
import processing.sound.*;
SoundFile file;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  background(255);

  // Load a soundfile from the /data folder of the sketch and play it back
  file = new SoundFile(this, "sample.mp3");
  if(file == null){
    throw new RuntimeException("La ruta del archivo es incorrecta");
  }
  file.play();
}

void draw() {
}
```

o usar Optional

```
import processing.sound.*;
import java.util.Optional;
Optional<SoundFile> file;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  background(255);

  // Load a soundfile from the /data folder of the sketch and play it back
  file = Optional.ofNullable(new SoundFile(this, "sample.mp3"));

  file.ifPresent(SoundFile::play());
}

void draw() {
}
```